# Formal way to suggest a time for a business call

Tags: business-language

If I was asked to set a time for a business call, what terms can I use to formally suggest/ determine a time?

Can I use the following in formal writing?

"5 O'clock would be good for me. Would this suit you?"

Comment: How formal do you want to be?

Comment: If my supervisor asked to arrange a time to speak over a phone and I want to write back to set a time in a formal way. Is it correct if I said (5 O'clock would be good for me)?

Answer (score 1):

I would say "I am available at 5:00 PM PST to talk to you."

Comment: You can't presume to know what time zone would apply in this question. What if they're in Bulgaria, or Japan?

Comment: Sorry it was just an example. I didn’t mean to assume he was on PST.